# IBM - Kernel problems

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, ubuntu-14.04, update, ibm-xseries

I bought an IBM x3850 and wanted to install Ubuntu on it. Then it said, that it can not find hard drives...
After some time i figured out that I need to type in the kernel parameter iommu=soft.
The installation worked fine..
Then there was a update.. The next time I started the system it said, that cpu #11 (number changed at the different starts) froze for 22seconds..
I rebooted the buttom via the powerbutton and selected ubuntu with the old kernel to start.. Then it worked fine..
What is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

On IBM website I only see RedHat/SUSE driver for your server model

Ubuntu is not listed, use it at your own risk.

I would try CentOS, as its the same core as RedHat, but that depend on your need.

Comment: I am using this server for rendering. But yes, if centos does not make any problems, i will think about installing it. I asked, because Ubuntu is my favourite os...

Comment: @rudolf97 Ubuntu lack server hardware support, seen compatibility problem with some HP server latelly too. I guess they put effort in other part of the distro. Kinda bad, as I agree its a good distro.

Comment: Isn't there a workaround for ubuntu? Because I would really like this os, my network is build on ubuntu and apt..

Comment: Something like porting the driver to ubuntu?

Comment: We talk about a production server with something not well tested?

Comment: It is used for rendering, and it isn't turned on often.

Comment: Then I would continue to use it as is, as I seen it boot.

Comment: Yes but always turning it off via powerbutton and then restarting it with an older kernel is also not a good solution..

Comment: Dont use that OS then :/ or use another computer for that task

Comment: Yes I think there is no other solution than installing opensuse... :-/

Comment: I tried to install opensuse. But when I choose Installation from the menu, the three loading symbols appear. Then it goes to a black screen... Whats wrong?